# Change google form questions based on spreadsheet and other questions

Tags: google-forms

I'm currently working on some code for a Google Form for a family football pool we do every year. I have it made to where the user selects their name from a list of competitors and then selects the team they want to pick that week. Each player cannot pick a team more than once and no more than 8 players can select any given team in one week.

Is there a way to gray out teams based on the teams a player already picked? I have a spreadsheet with everyone's name and the teams they picked. I manually update it based on last weeks results, each player is listed in a row with all the teams they picked in the cells next to their name.

Also how do I gray out teams that have already been picked by 8 players that week?